# Can't start tutorial scrapy smoothly

Tags: python, scrapy

I had started scrapy with Official Tutorial, but I can't go with it successfully.My code is totally same with official one.

```
import scrapy
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Quotes';

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url,callback = self.parse);

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split('/')[-2];
        print('--------------------------------->>>>');
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            yield {
                'text': quote.css('span.text::text').get(),
                'author': quote.css('small.author::text').get(),
                'tags': quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').getall(),
            }
```

When i execute it on CMD with instruction (scrapy crawl Quotes) and the result like this:

```
2020-12-20 10:00:25 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/> (referer: None)
2020-12-20 10:00:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
StopIteration: <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 55, in mustbe_deferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 58, in process_spider_input
    return scrape_func(response, request, spider)
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\scraper.py", line 149, in call_spider
    warn_on_generator_with_return_value(spider, callback)
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 245, in warn_on_generator_with_return_value
    if is_generator_with_return_value(callable):
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 230, in is_generator_with_return_value
    tree = ast.parse(dedent(inspect.getsource(callable)))
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\ast.py", line 47, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, flags,
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    def parse(self, response):
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
2020-12-20 10:00:26 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-12-20 10:00:26 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
```

---

I check it many times but I still do not know how to deal with it!

Answer (score 0):

There is a `IndentationError`.Need to fix code indentation. Its work fine.

Comment: I know the error is IndentationError.When I eliminate 'yield' of function 'parse'. My program can execute successfully. But i check it many times on indentation, still error

Comment: No need the ; end of the line. remove it.

Comment: def parse(self, response):
  page = response.url.split('/')[-2];
  print('--------------------------------->>>>');
  for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
   yield {
                'text': quote.css('span.text::text').get(),
                'author': quote.css('small.author::text').get(),
                'tags': quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').getall(),
            }

Comment: If i erase the yield, the program can execute smoothly

Answer (score -1):

It is not about the yield, I think either all the semicolons or maybe the last comma after getall()

`'tags': quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').getall(),`

might cause the interpreter to expect sth. else.

Remove the semicolons and the last comma - does it still not work?

The error output shows the indentation error at:

```
def parse
^
```

this tells you, that something before there caused it, so I guess it should be the first semicolon.